# TALLY Trial Balance xml with dates

Tags: xml, tally, tdl

```xml
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
    </HEADER>

    <BODY>
        <EXPORTDATA>
            <REQUESTDESC>
                <!--Specify the Report Name here-->
                <REPORTNAME>Trial Balance</REPORTNAME>
                <STATICVARIABLES>
                    <!--Show the Opening balance-->
                    <DSPSHOWOPENING>YES</DSPSHOWOPENING>
                    <!--Show the transactions Dr/Cr-->
                    <DSPSHOWTRANS>YES</DSPSHOWTRANS>
                    <!--This will fetch detailed TB-->
                    <EXPLODEALLLEVELS>YES</EXPLODEALLLEVELS>
                    <EXPLODEFLAG>YES</EXPLODEFLAG>
                    <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                </STATICVARIABLES>
            </REQUESTDESC>
        </EXPORTDATA>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

I am using this xml schema to get Trial balance. It is giving me the results I can also  get it for periods however, I want to it for monthly in such a way that it give me dates as well. How can I do that? Is that even possible? Tally xml schema gives only the name and amount by default not the dates. Even on their official web page it does not show dates at all. How to extract for monthly data in such a way that Dates are captured in output as well?

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it 2 ways**

- sending the same xml by applying date filters for each month

  ```
       <STATICVARIABLES>
      .......
   <!-- * Replace YYYYMMDD with month stating and ending dates in YYYYMMDD format -->
          <SVFROMDATE TYPE="DATE">yyyymmdd</SVFROMDATE>
           <SVTODATE TYPE="DATE">yyyymmdd</SVTODATE>
       </STATICVARIABLES>
  ```
- Another will be creating custom TDL report according to your needs
  and send it in TDL message

Comment: Hey sai, well I think I have tried it. This does give me a Trial Balance with specific period however, I don't think this will include <DATE> Tag. So, even if I get for 1 month. I won't know which amount corresponds to which date. In Tally, I think we can get that by pressing Alt+N. I want date tags as well.

Comment: You cannot get data field in response in this report.but we don't require that
we are sending the request to get specific month(Ex:April) trial balance, So all response amounts belongs to that month only (April)